# Jasypt with Spring ... Logger Config

Tags: spring, logging, log4j, jasypt

While using Jasypt in Spring the logger level in the load properties method of the PropertiesLoaderSupport class is set to Info

```
protected void loadProperties(Properties props) throws IOException {
        if (this.locations != null) {
            for (Resource location : this.locations) {
                if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                    logger.info("Loading properties file from " + location);
                }
```

The above code block returns true while using Jasypt whereas it returns false with Spring due to while I get lot of unwanted log message.

Can somebody suggest how can I make it to return false through configurations .

I am using log4j for my application as well .

Thanks

Comment: @farvilain  - Can you have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find out the result after a lot of search ... To resolve this issue we have to set the Logger properties for Jasypt in the Logger configuration being used for the application . For example

name="log4j.logger.org.jasypt">ERROR

That will resolve the issue .